# How do I import JavaScript files that uses functions in other local files in Vue cli without getting undefined errors?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have been trying to convert an HTML template (includes JS and CSS) to VueJS app. The template is structured and modularised in such a way that JavaScript functions from other local JavaScript files are used repeatedly within other local files.

The problem now is that I am getting undefined variable errors in my JavaScript files when imported within a Vue single-page app.

For example:

file validate.js has validate_username() and validate_email()

file login.js has login()

file register.js has register() but uses validate_username() and login() from other files.

How I tried to import the files in Vue:

```js
import './assets/validate.js';
import './assets/login.js';
import './assets/register.js';
```

I am getting validate_username() not defined in register.js

Comment: are using a bundler like vue cli or webpack? please share also one file content

Comment: I am using vue-cli.

Answer (score 1):

You have to export the functions from their files:

```
// login.js
export const login = function() {
  ...
}
```

So that you can import them:

```js
import { login } from './assets/login.js';
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a `default` export rather than a named export:

```js
export default function() {  // login
  ...
}
```

```
import login from './assets/login.js';
```